# JS & Bootstrap - output doesn't work

Tags: javascript, function, input, output

Does someone know how to make a right output in a browser using JS and bootstrap? The input can't be saved in H5 within form class. It doesn't work with bootstrap, but with pure HTML and JS, it works, that's why I am asking for help. Thanks in advance.

```js
function myFunction() {
    let input = document.getElementById('input');
    let output = document.getElementById('output');
    output.innerHTML = input.value;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Issue App</title>   
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Issue App interface -->
        
        <div class="container">
            <h1>JS Issue App <small>by Adam</small></h1>
            <h2 style="font-size:medium";>Give a worthy feedback and make a huge change!</h2>
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <h3>Add New Issue:</h3>
                <form id="issueInputForm">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="input">Description</label>
               
               <!-- input --> 
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Describe the issue" id="input" >
                    </div>                             
                   
               <!-- button -->    
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="myFunction()">Add</button>
                   
               <!-- output doesn't save in a browser, and resets after the button is clicked -->    
                   <h5 id="output"></h5>
               
               </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div id="issuesList">
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="footer">
                    <p>&copy adam.pl</p>
                </div>
                   </div>
        
                                 

             
                
        <!-- Scripts -->
        
        <script src="http://chancejs.com/chance.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Jquery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- JS -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you set the button to be a submit button, you make the form submit and thus reload the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible issues.

1. Change the `button type="submit"` to `button type ="button"` or add `event.preventDefault()` inside the function `myFunction`
2. It is not clear what `chance.min.js` is doing or whether it is dependent on jquery/bootstrap. It is better to reorder the script files

   ```
       <!-- Jquery -->
       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <!-- Bootstrap -->
       <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <!-- JS -->
       <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your button type from `submit` to `button`. This way the form does not get submitted which would change the current page... You could also use `event.preventDefault()` in your handler, where event is the first parameter...

```js
function myFunction() {
    let input = document.getElementById('input');
    let output = document.getElementById('output');
    output.innerHTML = input.value;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Issue App</title>   
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Issue App interface -->
        
        <div class="container">
            <h1>JS Issue App <small>by Adam</small></h1>
            <h2 style="font-size:medium";>Give a worthy feedback and make a huge change!</h2>
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <h3>Add New Issue:</h3>
                <form id="issueInputForm">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="input">Description</label>
               
               <!-- input --> 
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Describe the issue" id="input" >
                    </div>                             
                   
               <!-- button -->    
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="myFunction()">Add</button>
                   
               <!-- output doesn't save in a browser, and resets after the button is clicked -->    
                   <h5 id="output"></h5>
               
               </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div id="issuesList">
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="footer">
                    <p>&copy adam.pl</p>
                </div>
                   </div>
        
                                 

             
                
        <!-- Scripts -->
        
        <script src="http://chancejs.com/chance.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Jquery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- JS -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```